# Named CSS grid lines with SCSS

Tags: css, sass, css-grid

I'm experimenting with the new [CSS Grid Layout system](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout) in [codepen.io](https://codepen.io/Kaivosukeltaja/pen/XMGYmJ?editors=1100). It has an interesting feature called [named grid lines](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Grid_Layout/Layout_using_Named_Grid_Lines) that allows defining custom names for the grid lines between the columns and rows. Unfortunately I can't seem to get the feature to work because SCSS doesn't approve of the `[line-name]` syntax.

```
#container.named {
  grid-template-columns: [main-start] 100px [content-start] 1fr [content-end] 100px [main-end]; // Will not pass SCSS validation :(

  .one {
    grid-column: content-start / content-end;
  }
}
```

The code above should create a CSS grid that has two 100px wide columns on the sides with a column that fills the rest of the element's width in the center. This part works fine. I then try to give the grid lines custom names and place the `.one` element in the middle column but Codepen's SCSS preprocessor (as well as all the other compilers I've tried) refuses to compile the whole thing, saying `Invalid CSS after "...plate-columns: ": expected expression (e.g. 1px, bold), was "[main-start] 10..."`

Is there some way to force SCSS to compile this style as-is without parsing it (or express this in another way that compiles) or will I have to rewrite my experiment with regular CSS?

Comment: Can you explain bit clearly on what you are trying to do here?

Comment: @Mr.Alien, Explanation and link to MDN documentation added.

Comment: Aah, you were looking for string interpolation :)

Comment: For what it’s worth, using the `unquote(..)` function would also work.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try putting whole your CSS line to string:

```
$gridTplCols: "[main-start] 100px [content-start] 1fr [content-end] 100px [main-end]";

grid-template-columns: #{$gridTplCols};
```

Comment: The compass compiler should address this, but this solution is perfect for the time being, thanks!