# Is it possible to use native css functions in sass?

Tags: css, sass

The root of my problem is using CSS4 variables with css functions that is overridden by SASS mixins.

SASS overrides `rgb` and `rgba` to help with passing hex to them, for instance. Problem is I am using the new CSS4 spec which allows for variables.

What I want to do is:

```
background-color: rgba(var(--theme-color, 0.5)
```

Now this would work fine if SASS hadn't taken over and expect a different input.

So is it possible to override this mixin somehow, so I just get it output as a normal css value?

Comment: Put your css code as plain string: [Similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206860/named-css-grid-lines-with-scss)

Comment: Unless I misunderstood you, this will not work.
https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LydWMd

Comment: Yes, you understand wrong. `$rgba: "rgba(var(--theme-color, 0.5)";
  background-color: #{$rgba};`

Comment: Brilliant. Thank  you for giving me the direction as well. Now created a working override: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LydWMd

Comment: I suggest do not use override, as future development may lead to issues where not noticing existence of overriding function.

Comment: I agree. In actual environment I will probably create a native-rgba mixin

Comment: css-variables is not "CSS4". But you're not the first to refer to it as such. Just where are people getting the impression that css-variables is "CSS4" anyway? Who or what source exactly is making that up?

Comment: This is a natural result of making a pact with the devil, by which I am referring to deciding to use SASS in the first place. It is the jQuery of CSS frameworks. Now could be an opportune time to cut it loose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Justinas who led me in the right direction on this question.

Although it could be argued that this is a duplicate of
[Named CSS grid lines with SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206860/named-css-grid-lines-with-scss), I still want to share the solution that is more spesific to what I tried to solve.

Here is a codepen of a rather ok solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/LydWMd

Basically just creating a mixin that either overrides(as pointed out, not necessarely what you want unless you know you will never use the built-in sass functionality in your project) or an addition:

```
@function native-rgba($string, $opacity) {
  @return #{"rgba(#{$string}, #{$opacity})"};
}
```