# grid-template-columns in less

Tags: css, less, css-grid

I am trying to make a grid layout in CSS but using .less

I have this

```
.item-view-component{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: [grid-col-first] 20% [grid-col-2] 20% [grid-col-3] 20% [grid-col-4] 20% [grid-col-last] 20%;
    grid-template-rows: [grid-row-first] 20% [grid-row-2] 20% [grid-row-3] 20% [grid-row-4] 20% [grid-row-last] 20%;
}
```

Sadly, i can't find a way to correctly name my columns and row.

it return a compilation error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Named CSS grid lines with SCSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43206860/named-css-grid-lines-with-scss)

Answer (score 3):

You can use variables and the e()-function (it doesn't change the content, it only removes the quotes):

```
@gridcolumns: "[grid-col-first] 20% [grid-col-2] 20% [grid-col-3] 20% [grid-col-4] 20% [grid-col-last] 20%";
@gridrows: "[grid-row-first] 20% [grid-row-2] 20% [grid-row-3] 20% [grid-row-4] 20% [grid-row-last] 20%";
.item-view-component{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: e(@gridcolumns);
    grid-template-rows: e(@gridrows);
}
```